# Why am I getting a Null Pointer Exception in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to simulate vehicles parking on a parking place of a company. I have planned and unplanned cars. I have a schedule set up for the planned cars, which is working fine. The planned cars with the arrival and departure time and some other parameters are stored in the Anylogic Database.
For the source "unplannedCars" I wanted to inject them by the inject function call. The unplannedCar would be set on exit. But as soon as I try to inject some unplanned Cars, the model gives me a Null Pointer Exception Error. Has this something to do with my model taking the values of the Database?
I tried to fix it by adding the cars manually to a population and using the enter block. But there, I had the problem of using the road traffic library in combination with it.

Edit: I noticed the NullPointerException happens only if the "eOrV" block is used.

Edit2: I also tried to set default values for the agent and for the database. Now I get following Error with a NullPointerException: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYkGF.png)

Help is appreciated.
[unplannedCarSourceImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1swWk.png) [plannedCarSourceImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ8It.png) [Erorrmessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcXfi.png) [modelimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiqgH.png) [Errormessage2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlNbP.png) [SelectOutputBlock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91nM0.png)

Comment: Click on the blue link in the error message taking you to "Main.java.1351". This will tell you where exactly the error is caused. Maybe that helps you already, else share that with us as well :)

Comment: I edited the post with the images of the oOrV Select Output Block and the first Error Message. If needed i can also share the model

Answer (score 0):

The NPE in the SelectOutput is telling you that there is no field `motortype` in the incoming agent.

Likely, your `Car` agent type does not have such a field or it is indeed `null`, i.e. the String is completely empty and not initialized.

Make sure that agents passing through the SelectOutput have a field `motortype` of type String and that it contains *some* String.

Comment: Thats the strange part. I have default values set for the agent parameter and still it is initialised with null. But I managed to solve the problem otherwise. Thank you anyways Benjamin! :)

Comment: cool, do share the solution here so future users with a similar problem can learn :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a workaround for that problem. As I have a database and a schedule for my agents, I also wanted to control them manually. So I needed to use the Schedule and the inject function. By using the schedule and set parameter from DB, I was able to solve the Null Pointer Exception problem. Still I dont know what caused the Null Pointer Exception as I had default values set for my agents.